# Firebase Cloud Messaging with Apple push notifications stopped working when I changed my app Bundle ID

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, apple-push-notifications

I have an App that I had to change the Bundle-ID for. Once I did this Push Notifications stopped working. I replaced the app on Firebase with one with the new Bundle-ID and re-downloaded the GoogleService-info.plist. I have also created a new APNs authentication key and re-uploaded it. I have also added all the necessary code as specified on the Firebase documentation (and I have a similar app with the same code that works).

However, when I run the app on my phone it does not receive any push notifications. I have tested it by creating a test notification on my firebase console and sending the notification both to the device FCM token and a topic the device is subscribed to, with no success.

I am relatively new this so let me know if there's any other information needed.

Comment: Open the Google whatever the info.plist is.  The bundle id is stated in it.  You need to go to the Console, changing bundle ids, creating a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I found a problem in last version and switched to
firebase_messaging: 11.2.8
and Its working